# Pandas: Group by bi-monthly date field

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group by hospital staff working hours bi monthly. I have raw data on daily basis which look like below.

```
date       hourse_spent emp_id  
9/11/2016     8          1  
15/11/2016    8          1  
22/11/2016    8          2  
23/11/2016    8          1
```

How I want to group by is.

```
cycle                 hourse_spent      emp_id   
1/11/2016-15/11/2016      16                 1
16/11/2016-31/11/2016      8                 2
16/11/2016-31/11/2016      8                 1
```

I am trying to do the same with grouper and frequency in pandas something as below.

```
data.set_index('date',inplace=True)
print data.head()
dt = data.groupby(['emp_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='MS')])['hours_spent'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('date')

#df.resample('10d').mean().interpolate(method='linear',axis=0)
print dt.resample('SMS').sum()
```

I also tried `resampling`

```
df1 = dt.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(15, 'd')).sum()
data.set_index('date',inplace=True)
df1 = data.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(15, 'd')).sum()
```

But this is giving data of 15 days interval not like 1 to 15 and 15 to 31.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were *almost* there. This will do it -

```
dt = df.groupby(['emp_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='SM')])['hours_spent'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('date')

emp_id  date    hours_spent
1   2016-10-31  8
1   2016-11-15  16
2   2016-11-15  8
```

The `freq='SM'` is the concept of semi-months which will use the `15th` and the last day of every month

Answer (score 2):

**Put DateTime-Values into Bins**

If I got you right, you basically want to put your values in the date column into bins. For this, pandas has the `pd.cut()` function included, which does exactly what you want.

Here's an approach which might help you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'hours'  : 8,
  'emp_id' : [1,1,2,1],
  'date'   : [pd.datetime(2016,11,9),
              pd.datetime(2016,11,15),
              pd.datetime(2016,11,22),
              pd.datetime(2016,11,23)]
     })
bins_dt = pd.date_range('2016-10-16', freq='SM', periods=3)
cycle = pd.cut(df.date, bins_dt)
df.groupby([cycle, 'emp_id']).sum()
```

Which gets you:

```
cycle                    emp_id hours 
------------------------ ------ ------
(2016-10-31, 2016-11-15] 1      16    
                         2      NaN   
(2016-11-15, 2016-11-30] 1      8     
                         2      8
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar question, here was my solution:

```
df1['BiMonth'] = df1['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=-1) + pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd()
df1['BiMonth'] = df1['BiMonth'].dt.to_period('D')
```

The construction "df1['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=-1)" will take whatever is in the date column and -1 day.

The construction "+ pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd()" converts it to a bimonthly basket, but its off by a day unless you reduce the reference date by 1.

The construction "df1['BiMonth'] = df1['BiMonth'].dt.to_period('D')" cleans out the time so you just have days.